# What is this called and how could I implemented this?

Tags: ios

I want to implement the scrolls like the one in Clock where you use it to select the options for the Timer.

Timer:
[image: Timer]

I am sorry that I do not know what it is really called.

Many thanks.

Comment: Always look at the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios) before asking a question like this.

Comment: These are called Pickers and they are bread-and-butter in iOS development.  A 10 second Google will return the article that describes them

Comment: Sorry, english is not my first language so I did not know the keyword to search.

Answer (score 0):

Learn [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) , this is your answer